# Sqlite transactions in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sqlite, for-loop, transactions

Accordingly with nodejs sqlite library (https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) you can serialize a sql transaction with db.serialize function. All executions in this function will be executed in the specified order.
But with a for loop how can i get the information about the transaction will be success or fail?

```
function transaction(callback) {
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.run("BEGIN");

        for(...) {
            db.run("INSERT", function(err) {
                //this code is not serialized with the parent serialize function (this is my problem)
                //if one run throw error i must resolve the callback with the error code

                if (err)
                    callback("error");
            });
        }

        db.run("END");

        callback("ok");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before start transaction you can define some vars e.g. `var results = [];`. On complete each query inside callback you can collect error or null as `results.push(err)` and check `results.length`. When `results.length` equals to length of `for` then all queries executed and now check `results.every((i) => i === null)` value. If true then do `commit` else `rollback`.

---

Much better to control flow is use async module.

```
'use strict'
var async = require('async');
...
db.run('begin', function(err){
    if (err)
        return console.log(err);

    let run = (sql, callback) => db.run(sql, callback);    
    async.eachSeries(sqls, run, function(err){
        db.run((err) ? 'rollback' : 'commit', ...)
    })
})
```

If you add `begin` to sqls then code will be more simple.

Comment: Thanks :) The problem with your solution is that for a single connection only one thread can call the function otherwise the "transaction on transaction error" occurs.